# Calculating event counts per user per event, including counts of 0

Tags: sql, presto

I have a table with user events, and another table with the names of all events in the system.

What I need is per-event counts for each user, including events of which they had 0.

Dialect is ANSI SQL, unsure of version. The database is Presto 0.186.

Here's an example:

```
with
event_names (name) as (values
  ('event_1'), ('event_2'), ('event_3'), ('event_4')
)
, events (user_id, event_name, occurred_at) as (values
    ('id1', 'event_1', timestamp '2017-10-10 00:01:00')
  , ('id1', 'event_2', timestamp '2017-10-10 00:02:00')
  , ('id1', 'event_2', timestamp '2017-10-10 00:03:00')
  , ('id2', 'event_2', timestamp '2017-10-11 00:01:00')
  , ('id2', 'event_3', timestamp '2017-10-11 00:02:00')
  , ('id2', 'event_3', timestamp '2017-10-11 00:03:00')
  , ('id2', 'event_4', timestamp '2017-10-11 00:03:00')
  , ('id3', 'event_1', timestamp '2017-10-12 00:03:00')
  , ('id3', 'event_4', timestamp '2017-10-12 00:04:00')
)

select user_id, event_name, count(*) as event_count, sum(count(*)) over (partition by user_id) as total_events
from events
group by 1, 2
order by 1, 2;
```

This query naturally gives me only the counts for events the user did send:

```
 user_id | event_name | event_count 
---------+------------+-------------
 id1     | event_1    |           1 
 id1     | event_2    |           2 

 id2     | event_2    |           1 
 id2     | event_3    |           2 
 id2     | event_4    |           1 

 id3     | event_1    |           1 
 id3     | event_4    |           1
```

What I need is the following:

```
 user_id     |  name   | event_count 
-------------+---------+-------------
 id1         | event_1 |           1
 id1         | event_2 |           2
 id1         | event_3 |           0
 id1         | event_4 |           0

 id2         | event_1 |           0
 id2         | event_2 |           1
 id2         | event_3 |           2
 id2         | event_4 |           0

 id3         | event_1 |           1
 id3         | event_2 |           0
 id3         | event_3 |           0
 id3         | event_4 |           1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate all the rows using a `cross join`.  Then bring in the data that exists:

```
select u.user_id, en.event_name, count(e.user_id) as event_count,
       sum(count(e.user_id)) over (partition by user_id) as total_events
from (select distinct user_id from events) u cross join
     (select distinct event_name from events) en left join
     events e
     on e.user_id = u.user_id and e.event_name = en.event_name
group by 1, 2
order by 1, 2;
```

If you have other tables with the lists of users or events, then you can use those instead of the subqueries.